# GNU c++ compiler option to flag if (a = b)

Tags: c++, gcc, gnu

Having brain spasm this morning. Can't remember the GNU compiler option to flag

```
if (a = b)
```

as a warning/error because it is an assignment and not a condition.

Comment: `-Wall` includes a commetn on that (mentioned here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions ). Is that an option?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to enable all warnings and see what is reported:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc=0) ;
}
```

compile with `-Wall`

you will get the warning:

```
<source>: In function 'int main(int, char**)':

<source>:3:12: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]

    3 |     if(argc=0) ;

      |        ~~~~^~

Compiler returned: 0
```

So the option is: `-Wparentheses`

https://godbolt.org/z/6ac1zG

Comment: Also see the docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer that was the lazy way :). Documentation is long

Comment: IDK, I just googled it and got the docs. Seems even lazier :P

Comment: Works for this case, but  note that in general `-Wall` (and even `-Wextra`) won't enable all warnings the compiler can produce (despite the name!).

Comment: @psmears we have `-pedantic` as well. If all 3 do not enable some needed warnings it means that the programmer is experienced enough to know how to find them

Comment: @P__J__ *sad `-Wshadow` noises*